# Trigger Cloud Function across Pub/Sub Subscription

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to trigger a Cloud Function when I receive a message via Pub/Sub Subscriber. This subscriber is calling to another project (I'm able to see the messages in my project). But now, I need to trigger a Cloud Function to consume the message.

Do you have any idea how I should follow?

Answer (score 2):

You can't plug a Cloud Functions in project A on a PubSub topic in a project B. You need to deploy a HTTP functions and to create a push subscription to call the function.

***Note**: you can create your push subscription in the project A or in the project B. All depends who will be charged for the subscription cost.*

Comment: I have following use case: 
Project A publishes messages on specific topic. Project B needs to subscriber to that topic. Recently, I've subscribed to Project A since Project B (here I settinged up via PULL) and I've been able to receive the messages. At this point, Do I need to change to PUSH and then deploy a HTML Cloud Function  to consumer the messages?

Comment: When you PULL the message with Cloud Functions you create a subscription to pull them. It's the same situation as PUSH subscription to a HTTP Functions. You have to create a PULL subscription that you can create in the Project A or Project B. The problem comes when you deploy your cloud functions with `--trigger-topic` argument. In that case, cross project is not allowed.

Comment: here are issues about this => https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62373846 and https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173534853

Comment: You can try to use a dataflow job as a 'bridge' between projects - to listen to one topic in the project A and send messages into another topic of a project B. The drawback - the cost (which might be OK if the volumes as huge, or your have many incoming topic in the project A). The potential benefit - the dataflow job can do much more than juct copy messages from one project to another.